# Cannot implicitly convert type List<List<T>> to IList<IList<T>>

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on some problems on Leetcode and coding in C#, and problems which require a collection of collections require a return type of IList<IList<<int>>.

I am failing to understand why I get the following error, when I return a type of List<List<int>> :

*error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Collections.Generic.IList>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) (in Solution.cs)*

List<T> implements IList<T>...so why is it that I am getting such errors?

I've also tried instantiating an IList<List<T>> and I get the same type of error as well. I'm genuinely confused. It seems there is something that I am failing to understand correctly about the type parameters for this generic type.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: I quote `are you missing a cast?`.  That's really the problem.  It expects you to return an interface and you're not.  Change the definition.  `IList<int> foo = new List<int>`.  Or an explicit cast `return (IList<int>) foo`.  Either way.  This is fundamentally about strong typing.

Answer (score 0):

The way how type arguments of generics work is sometimes counterintuitive and different from language to language.

Suppose that you have a generic type `G<T>` and two types `A` and `A1`. Now, supposing that `A1` derives from `A`, this does not imply that `G<A1>` is a subtype of `G<A>`!

The reason behind this is a type safety concept called *variance* and, for this particular case, *invariance*. In simple words, the only subtype of `G<A>` is `G<A>` itself.

To relate the general rule above to your scenario, `G<T>` is `IList<T>` (the outer one), `A` is `IList<int>` (the inner one) and `A1` is `List<int>`.

To solve your issue, instead of declaring and `IList<List<T>>` as you said in the last paragraph of your question, you may declare and return a `List<IList<T>>` (note: **swapped** with respect to your declaration) or even directly a `IList<IList<T>>`.

Finally, keep in mind that, even if the error message talks about a missing cast, there should be no need for any casts and everything can be solved type-safely.

If you could provide the snippet that has the error, I can point out more concretely where the issue is and what's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score -2):

If you have a list

```cs
List<List<int>> listOfLists = new List<List<int>>();
```

and you have some `IList<int> someList`

you can't do this

```cs
listOfLists.Add(someList);
```

because `listOfLists` is expecting `List<int>` as an input. Basically you can implicitly convert `List<int>` to `IList<int>` for *output*, but you can't implicitly convert `IList<int>` to `List<int>` for *input*

What you can do is just define your original list as `IList<IList<int>>`

```cs
IList<IList<int>> listOfLists = new List<IList<int>>();
```

and you can add `List<int>` or `IList<int>` to that list and return it matching your required output.